# DBUS get free disk space of usb memory

Tags: debian, busybox, d-bus

I'm trying to determine how much disk space is free on an USB memory device by using a DBUS connector (`sdbus-c++`). For receiving signals of the connection status of the usb memory I use the `org.freedesktop.UDisks2` service.

This works very well, but I can't find any property with the "free disk space" information.

Do I need to use another service for this feature or how can I get this information? Currently I use a Debian System but after my first tests I will switch to a embedded busybox system (just in case this info is important).

Comment: UDisks seemingly deals with raw disks and partitions, thus it doesn't report this info. You could use this instead: https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-get-available-filesystem-space-on-linux-a-c-function-and-a-cpp-example/

Comment: + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992171/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-free-disk-space-for-a-directory-in-linux

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thx for your help - since I use C++17 I will use std::filesystem to get the information. Maybe I'm to lazy but I was hoping that a DBUS service offers a signal with the info when the memory is running low :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Udisks is reall into dealing with the hardware side of storage devices, up to mounting partitions/volumes. What file systems are on these partitions, and how much free space they have, is a bit out of scope for Udisks2. Some file systems that you might mount using Udisks don't even understand the concept of "free space" (like ISO9669)

From the top of my head, and with a bit of research into the available DBUS interfaces, I don't think a "free space" property is exposed to DBUS. Well, hacky but working workaround is just execing `df /path/to/mount`. (Many file systems need to be mounted, even if only read-only, to estimate the amount of free space. Free space and space used is, by the way, a thing that's surprisingly complex under the hood, for many file systems.)

Now, especially if you later on shrink this down to a busybox-based minimal system, you might not want to use a GNU coreutil `df` execution to read something that you then need to parse from text, just to get information that you could have gotten yourself. Seeing you're doing C++ (top of my head, not even trying to compile this), and assuming you don't have C++17's [`std::filesystem::space`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/space), which is of course way less hassle than using DBUS to begin with:

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>

std::string mountpoint;
/*
 * Get the mount point using org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem's "MountPoints" property, see
 * http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem.html#gdbus-property-org-freedesktop-UDisks2-Filesystem.MountPoints
 * We'll act as if you already did this and it was stored in `mountpoint`.
 */

// Terrible naming choices made the structure typename be the same as the function name, so even in C++ we have to use `struct`. Wah.
struct statvfs filesystem_info;
statvfs(mountpoint.c_str(), &filesystem_info);
auto bytes_per_block = filesystem_info.f_bsize;
auto blocks_free_for_unprivileged_users = filesystem_info.f_bavail;
auto blocks_free_total = filesystem_info.f_bfree;
```

Comment: Thx for your detailed answer and the code snippet!
Since C++17 you can also use std::filesystem to get the free space, this is pretty straight forward. If you use cmake: Don't forget to link your target with stdc++fs ;)

Comment: @B-S-E you should not have to link explicitly against stdc++fs, ever. Telling your compiler that it should be using `-std=c++17`, i.e. setting `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` in CMake, suffices, on anything where you did not explicitly *turn off* the standard library.

Comment: of course you are right - I have to use a quite old gnu compiler for my project (gcc 8.3). AFAIK since gcc > 9.1 linking against stdc++fs is no longer necessary.

Comment: @B-S-E seems you're right indeed: https://godbolt.org/z/qsevhvadG , change must have happened between 8.5 and 9.1